# How to get Access Report textbox to concatenate records from a table when the report is generated from a form?

Tags: sql, database, forms, vba, ms-access

Essentially this includes 3 components.

First is a form, here the user, via a listbox, chooses multiple names.

For example, they highlight the following names.

```
Jane
John
Bob
```

They click a button called "btnGenerate" and these three names get entered as seperate records into a table called "NameCriteria" like this:

```
ID    Name
1     Jane
2     John
3     Bob
```

Along with this, on-click of the button btnGenerate, a report is generated.

What I cannot seem to get working is that on the report, I hope to get a summary of what was selected on the form. I have a textbox on this report which I am trying to get to generate the following result

```
Jane, John, Bob
```

OR if there is only one name highlighted when the btnGenerate is clicked, the textbox will only display

```
Jane
```

I cannot seem to get this working. In the report, on the textbox, under the textbox's data/control source, I have entered the following code.

```
=[Forms]![Report]![lstName]
```

This just leaves the textbox blank. I have also tried referencing the table "NameCriteria" using

```
=[Table]![NameCriteria]![Name]
```

and I return #Error in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something along these lines, using ADO, but its been a long day, so there may be simpler solution.

```
Public Function CONCAT_SQL(strSQL As String) As String

Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim a As Variant

Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
r.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, 1

a = Split(r.GetString, Chr(13))
ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) - 1)

CONCAT_SQL = Join(a, ",")

End Function
```

Called like so,

```
me.textbox1.value = CONCAT_SQL("Select [Name] from [NameCriteria]")
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I'm a little confused, where would I be entering both these pieces of code? I'm guessing the second piece is in the "data" section of the textbox? But for the first piece, do I just create a module?